# Java + Spark simple joins

Tags: java, apache-spark, tuples

I'm completely new to Spark and I have to do this at my uni.

Here are 2 text files with data base.

User information: (id, email, language, location)

```
1   user1@test.com  EN  US
2   user2@test2.com EN  GB
3   user3@test3.com FR  FR
```

Transaction infromation: (transaction-id, product-id, user-id, purchase-amount, itemdescription)

```
1   1   1   300 prod1
2   1   2   300 prod1
3   1   2   300 prod2
4   2   3   100 prod2
5   1   3   300 prod3
```

My task is to provide a query like that:

User_id, count(product_id), location

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This is what we I had on my lesson (simple join)

JoinJob job = new JoinJob(sc);
        JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> results = job.joinData("./src/main/resources/transactions.txt", "./src/main/resources/users.txt");
        
        System.out.println(results.collect().get(0)._1);
        System.out.println(results.collect().get(0)._2);
        System.out.println(results.collect().get(1)._1);
        System.out.println(results.collect().get(1)._2);







Print:
1
US
2
FR

Comment: Please refer to the official documentation, read it and try something for real ! There is not even one spark functions in what you shared besides collect. SO isn't a homework writing platform.

Comment: @MichałBednarz If you are able to write SQL, use it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an simple example, so you can get started. But please please read the spark doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/)

```
val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
          (1, "user1@test.com", "EN", "US"),
          (2, "user2@test2.com", "EN", "GB"),
          (3, "user3@test3.com", "FR", "FR")
        ))
      .toDF("id", "email", "language", "location")

    val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
          (1, 1, 1, 300, "prod1"),
          (2, 1, 2, 300, "prod1"),
          (3, 1, 2, 300, "prod2"),
          (4, 2, 3, 100, "prod2"),
          (5, 1, 3, 300, "prod3")
        )
      ).toDF("transaction-id", "product-id","user-id", "purchase-amount", "itemdescription")


    val df2Count = df2.groupBy("user-id").count().alias("count_product_id")

    val result = df2Count.join(df1, df2Count("user-id") === df1("id"))

    result.select("user-id", "count", "location").show
```

Output:

```
+-------+-----+--------+
|user-id|count|location|
+-------+-----+--------+
|      1|    1|      US|
|      3|    2|      FR|
|      2|    2|      GB|
+-------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, I did upvote! I just have not enough reputation points to make it visible :)

Comment: Thanks @MichałBednarz